# Angular PrimeNG listbox cross label

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using angular 7.2.0 and primeng 7.0.0, i'm trying to show a list of elements in a listbox.

How can i cross the label of the selected element on the list instead of highlighting it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to try and inspect the element you are trying to modify using the browser's DevTools (play in the Style section until you reach the desired result) and then change it in your code.

As for the question, you want to remove the background for the selected state of the list item and then give the line-through text-decoration property. This should be the CSS part to solve your issue with the right selectors:

```
body .ui-listbox .ui-listbox-list .ui-listbox-item.ui-state-highlight {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Please note that the text color is changed to be visible after we remove the blue background. This is only for the highlighted state of a list box item (**.ui-listbox-item.ui-state-highlight**).

- If you are not sure how to use the inspect tool, please check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/) quick tutorial provided by Google developers. Hope this can be of any help

Comment: The fastest way to prioritize the properties for specific accessors is to put your CSS in the global styles.css. Your angular(cli).json file should put styles.css above everything else. So, go to styles.css and put that css bit there with background-body as inherit / transparent or none. That should work

Comment: If you want to better understand and learn more about angular styling, check [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) that gives a detailed overview of your options.